# OBIEE 12c Admin Tool - Duplicate definition - Metadata Script Execution Error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, business-intelligence, obiee, oracle-bi

I am trying to create a repository using the BISAMPLE as per the tutorials from oracle.
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/bi/bi1221/rpd/rpd.html
http://rakeshpatil002.blogspot.com/2014/11/bisample-schema.html

Oracle Database is also 12c

The user is loaded into ORCLPDB. I loaded it into ORCL: before but dropped the user after making that mistake.

But when I try to add them I get the following error message. 
I hope that you could please tell me what I am doing wrong or where I should look to fix this problem.
I can see all the tables when I am in SQL Developer logged in as BISAMPLE.
My environment is Windows 2016 Server.

Any help is appreciated. (the line in bold is the error) The error is from the admin tool.

Metadata Script Execution Error:

```
inQSError: 28004 duplicate defininition
DECLARE TABLE "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D" AS "SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"
 HAVING( 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."CUST_KEY" AS "CUST_KEY" TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION 53 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."NAME" AS "NAME" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 1020 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."TYPE_KEY" AS "TYPE_KEY" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 1020 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."FST_CONTACT_DT" AS "FST_CONTACT_DT" TYPE TIMESTAMP PRECISION 19 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."SEGMENT_KEY" AS "SEGMENT_KEY" TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION 53 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."INCOME_LVL" AS "INCOME_LVL" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 1020 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."STATUS_KEY" AS "STATUS_KEY" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 1020 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."LST_ORDER_DT" AS "LST_ORDER_DT" TYPE TIMESTAMP PRECISION 19 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."ADDRESS_KEY" AS "ADDRESS_KEY" TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION 53 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."MARITAL_ST" AS "MARITAL_ST" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 20 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."PREV_MARITAL_ST" AS "PREV_MARITAL_ST" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 20 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."PREV_MARITAL_ST_DT" AS "PREV_MARITAL_ST_DT" TYPE TIMESTAMP PRECISION 19 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."BIRTH_DT" AS "BIRTH_DT" TYPE TIMESTAMP PRECISION 19 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."CRDT_RATE" AS "CRDT_RATE" TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION 38 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    ERROR HERE
    **"biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."CUST_KEY" AS "CUST_KEY" TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION 53 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} ,**
    ERROR END
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."NAME" AS "NAME" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 1020 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."TYPE_KEY" AS "TYPE_KEY" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 1020 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."FST_CONTACT_DT" AS "FST_CONTACT_DT" TYPE TIMESTAMP PRECISION 19 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."SEGMENT_KEY" AS "SEGMENT_KEY" TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION 53 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."INCOME_LVL" AS "INCOME_LVL" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 1020 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."STATUS_KEY" AS "STATUS_KEY" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 1020 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."LST_ORDER_DT" AS "LST_ORDER_DT" TYPE TIMESTAMP PRECISION 19 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."ADDRESS_KEY" AS "ADDRESS_KEY" TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION 53 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."MARITAL_ST" AS "MARITAL_ST" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 20 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."PREV_MARITAL_ST" AS "PREV_MARITAL_ST" TYPE VARCHAR PRECISION 20 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."PREV_MARITAL_ST_DT" AS "PREV_MARITAL_ST_DT" TYPE TIMESTAMP PRECISION 19 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."BIRTH_DT" AS "BIRTH_DT" TYPE TIMESTAMP PRECISION 19 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} , 
    "biplatform_datasource"."".""."SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D"."CRDT_RATE" AS "CRDT_RATE" TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION 38 SCALE 0 NULLABLE VALUE TYPE  MAPPED COLUMN ''  MVLINK ''  DESCRIPTION  {} 
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Steve,

we ran into the same error.

We checked with a `SELECT * FROM all_tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SAMP_ADRESSES_D'` for the number of entries in the metadata catalogue of the Oracle database:

- occurred TWO times.

We found out that there were two different owners: `BISAMPLE` and `BISAMPLE_EXA`.

We dropped the table

`DROP TABLE BISAMPLE_EXA.SAMP_ADDRESSES_D`

and found out that in the configuration dialog of the new repository the duplicate entry for `SAMP_ADRESSES_D` vanished.

We repeated the `DROP TABLE` step for all duplicated tables as mentioned in our Oracle BI training guideline (I guess you used the same).

We observed that all duplicates were removed and the wizard allowed us to continue.

After that our machine suffered a virtual heart attack indicated by a blue scree of death :-(

Nevertheless we solved this problem that you also might have had. It is apparently a bug in Oracle BI; they were not able to distinguish between objects of different owners with the same object name.
If you know a location where to describe this error for the developers of Oracle (like Microsoft Connect) please feel free to add this to it.

Best regards

JP